# ffmpeg cut a video starting at n frames before a specific time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to cut a video (with ffmpeg) starting at `n` frames before a specific time, say 100 frames exactly before 00:08:05.042, is it possible ?

(even if I don't need it, is there a possibility to also specify a frame offset for the end ?)

Comment: Is audio present?

Comment: no, I suppress audio. It does a difference ?